# Rails uninitialized constant name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Character::Messagemissife):
uninitialized constant Mime::HTML
```

The error is coming from this line:

```
if @character.messagemissives
```

**character.rb**

```
has_many :messagemissives, dependent: :destroy
```

**messagemissive.rb**

```
class Messagemissive < Missive
  self.table_name = 'messagemissives'
  belongs_to :character      
end
```

**missive.rb**

```
class Missive < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

I have a class `Messagemissive`, but not `Messagemissife`. Of course, it looks like a typo error. But I can't find "Messagemissife" anywhere in any of my files. I've used the Find function in Sublime Text 2, I've used the mac Finder search, I've cleared the cache, I've restarted the server several times, I've restarted the computer several times. Still this error won't go away. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why name it `Messagemissive` in the first place? Calling something `messageletter` would be just as ridicoulous.

Comment: This is Rails trying to call `pluralize`/`singularize` on your model relation. See this post to add an exception for the `messagemissive` word (in the rails console, doing `'messagemissives'.singularize` returns `messagemissife`)

Comment: Max, there are good reasons for this which aren't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this behaviour because of rails's default naming convention. When you call `@character.messagemissives`, rails is actually looking for a model with it's corresponding singular term `Messagemissife` and not `Messagemissive`. You can confirm this by typing
`"Messagemissives".singularize` 
in rails console which will return you `"Messagemissife"`.
To fix this issue, either you can mention the class name with association like

```
has_many :messagemissives,  class_name: 'Messagemissive'
```

or as mentioned [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-plural), in `/config/initializers/inflections.rb`, just add

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'messagemissive', 'messagemissives'
end
```

Hope this will help.